# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where' in update statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to do UPDATE the data, but it is showing an error.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//Update
{
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SYSTEM2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=amresh;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE detail SET name='" + TxtBox_name.Text + "',address='" + TexBo_add.Text + "', WHERE contact_no='" + TexBo_num.Text + "'",con);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('record updated');", true);
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ooh, so many errors in such a tight space:

- the actual SQL error is just an unnecessary comma
- but: you have SQL injection problems
- and a missing dispose

I'm a big fan of using tools to help avoid pain. Here's the same using "dapper"'

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)) 
{
     con.Execute(@"update detail
         set name=@name, address=@address
         where contact_no = @num",
         new {
             name = TxtBox_name.Text,
             address = TexBo_add.Text,
             num = TexBo_num.Text
        });
}
```

Additionally, it might also want to be:

```
...
num = int.Parse(TexBo_num.Text)
...
```

But then - having code that mentions both UI controls and data access in the same method probably means your UI code is doing too much.

Answer (score 2):

First of all [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) would be all over this like a cheap suit.  Secondly, look at the [documenation of SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) for an example of how to update using parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `,`(comma) before `where`.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE detail SET name='" + TxtBox_name.Text + "',address='" + TexBo_add.Text + "', WHERE contact_no='" + TexBo_num.Text + "'", con);
                                                                                                                   ^
```

But I would recommend you to please use `Parameterized` query.

```
string query= "UPDATE detail SET name=@name, address=@address WHERE contact_no=@contactno";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TxtBox_Name.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TexBo_add.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactno", TexBo_num.Text);
```